# save videos to document directory without crash app in swift

Tags: swift3, file-manager

i have app which pick videos from photos library and save it to the document directory when i select one video and save it to document directory it's work good but when i select two videos or more i get crash my app please i need right way to save videos and images to document directory without crash my app

the following my code :

```
@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
 var getNumberFull = DealWithFileSystem.fetchNumberOfFilesInFolder(folderName: folderName + ".xcvg")

            for (_,asset) in self.dictionaryOfAssets.enumerated() {


                if asset.value.mediaType == .image {

                    if  let getNumberFromThumb = DealWithFileSystem.fetchNumberOfFilesInFolder(folderName: folderName) {
                        getNumberFull! = getNumberFromThumb
                        let filePathThumb = DealWithFileSystem.fetchFolderName(folderName: folderName)?.appendingPathComponent("Image \(getNumberFromThumb).png")
                        let fetchOption = PHImageRequestOptions()
                        fetchOption.isSynchronous = true
                        fetchOption.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                        fetchOption.resizeMode = .exact
                        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset.value, targetSize: CGSize(width:79.0,height:79.0), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: fetchOption, resultHandler: { (img, nil) in
                            if let convert = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img!) {
                                try! convert.write(to: filePathThumb!)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    let filePathFull = DealWithFileSystem.fetchFolderName(folderName: folderName + ".xcvg")?.appendingPathComponent("Image \(getNumberFull!).png")
                    let fetchOption = PHImageRequestOptions()
                    fetchOption.isSynchronous = true
                    PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset.value, options: nil, resultHandler: { (data, fetchOption, _, _) in
                        try! data?.write(to: filePathFull!)

                    })


                }else if asset.value.mediaType == .video {
                    let filePathThumb = DealWithFileSystem.fetchFolderName(folderName: folderName)?.appendingPathComponent("Video \(getNumberFull! + 1).jpg")
                    let fetchOption = PHImageRequestOptions()
                    fetchOption.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                    fetchOption.resizeMode = .exact
                    fetchOption.isSynchronous = true
                    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset.value, targetSize: CGSize(width:79.0,height:79.0), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: fetchOption, resultHandler: { (img, info) in
                        if let convertImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 1.0) {
                            try! convertImage.write(to: filePathThumb!)
                        }
                    })
                    let filePathFull = DealWithFileSystem.fetchFolderName(folderName: folderName + ".xcvg")?.appendingPathComponent("Video \(getNumberFull! + 1).mp4")
                    PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset.value, options: nil, resultHandler: { (AVAsset, AVAudio, info) in
                        let getUrlAsset = AVAsset as! AVURLAsset
                        if let convertVideo = NSData(contentsOf: getUrlAsset.url) {

                            convertVideo.write(to: filePathFull!, atomically: true)
                        }
                    })

                    getNumberFull! += 1
                }
            }

}
```

thanks Advance

Comment: Just don't load your data to memory. Use FileManager moveItem method instead of  
NSData(contentsOf

Comment: i can't move item from photos library to file manager i need to save theses images and videos to document directory

Comment: Create a new url and move it

Comment: if i use the move it then i can't save thumbnail for image and videos when i need to fetch theses item after i can't i think if i save it on the background thread but how can i use the background thread?

Comment: not related to your problem, why are you enumerating and discarding the index? just do a regular loop. change `for (_,asset) in self.dictionaryOfAssets.enumerated() {` to `for asset in dictionaryOfAssets {`